# NoMethodError (undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

NoMethodError (undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass):

This is the error i get when trying to use omniauth with Devise...

I am able to signup for the site with facebook...
but once i log out 
and try to log back in i get the

NoMethodError (undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass):

class Models::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @model = Model.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_model)

```
if @model.persisted?
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
  sign_in_and_redirect @model, :event => :authentication
else
  session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_model_registration_url
end
```

end

def passthru
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
    # Or alternatively,
    # raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end

end

model.rb

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    model = Model.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless model
    model = Model.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                         )
    end
  end


  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |model|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        model.email = data["email"] if model.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you implemented `find_for_facebook_oauth` method in your model? Can you show it?

Comment: i did add that...im going through the omniauth wiki...i will post right now

Comment: any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find_for_facebook_oauth` method is implicitly returning nil in cases where a model is found. You should explicitly return the model if it is found instead.

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  model = Model.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  return model if model
  model = Model.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                         )
end
```

Comment: On a side note, this is a bad name for the method since it's doing more than just finding something. It would make more sense as `find_or_create_for_facebook_oauth`

Comment: returning the model gives you a syntax error? Are you sure you wrote it correctly?

Comment: i just copied and pasted what you had

Comment: /Users/rickyahn/Sites/abatman-site/app/models/model.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Comment: My bad, I left in the `end` from your unless conditional. Fixed the example.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!!!!!!!!  THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!! THAT WORKED!!!!!!  HOLY MOLY IM GONNA ERECT A STATUE IN YOUR HONOR!!!

Comment: @user1502223 try this: "Thanks, that worked!". And please reserve that all caps stuff for youtube.

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  model = Model.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless model
  model = Model.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                     provider:auth.provider,
                     uid:auth.uid,
                     email:auth.info.email,
                     password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                     )
  end
  model #Add this here
end
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of your answer? Why does this work?

Comment: I'm a newbie to Rails, so I may be wrong on reasoning, but I believe that the ```unless``` returns ```nil``` if ```model``` is not ```nil```, when what you want to be returned is ```model```. Ruby returns the last thing it evaluates, so adding ```model``` at the end ensures that Ruby returns it.